# Jenkins Plugin - Enable Stage View Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-2

How to enable Pipeline stage view Plugin in Jenkins 2.0. There is no option available to enable the plugin

Answer (score 0):

You have to review if  you already have it installed in the Plugins options from Jenkins.

If you have it you will able to use it creating jobs of type 'Pipeline'.

Also, when you install Jenkisn 2.0 and you select to install recommended plugins it will install all those plugins of Pipeline (Multibranch pipeline, pipeline, pipeline stage view, etc)

Comment: @eliyas Check if [Stage View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Stage+View+Plugin) is installed?